# Objective-C: how to get 123 from 0.123 or generically xyz... from 0.xyz...?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, fractions

As title states, if I have a float, I need to get the fraction part as an integer, how do I do it?

I was thinking:

1. get index(position) of decimal point
2. then I can know how many digits after decimal point
3. get those digits as substring
4. convert it to an integer

is there any better/smarter way?

update:

I forgot to mention, the float has format like: X.YZ so there are at most two digits after decimal point.

Comment: What is your exact requirement? If you're using the float type, even a number like 12 might have an exact value of 12.000001. If the number is captured from the user, you should probably be using a char* or NSString instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 float temp=12.123;
NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",temp];
NSArray *arr=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
int tempInt=[[arr lastObject] intValue];
```

Comment: I picked your answer but I need to make some change in my case, as the 'temp' is a returned value from some method, it may be 12.12300001, but I only need 123 or even 12, so I changed %f to %.2f and removed the last 0 if there is any.

Comment: hmm need change as per your above requirement

Answer (score 9):

You use the [modf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/modf/) function:

```
double integral;
double fractional = modf(some_double, &integral);
```

refer this [fractional part of NSDecimalnumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355755/fractional-part-of-nsdecimalnumber)

Comment: Bad copy paste, I think you've meant `modff` - `modf` operates on doubles.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", value];
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
int num = [[arr objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
```

Comment: Small mistake: pointer on `int`? `intValue` returns `(int)`, not `(int *)`.

Answer (score 2):

Let take a example:
x = 129.567;

convert x into integer and put in y.
y = int(x);
so y = 129;

now subtract y from x.
so z = x-y;
z = .567

z = z*1000;
so z = 567

I think thats what you are looking for.

Comment: @Hector for 129.5678, after getting .5678 you can find the length of your fraction and multiply 10 that many times.
What say???

Comment: But I don't know how many digits after ., so if it is 1.1, then I will get 1000 instead of 1

Comment: @HZXU you have to find the length of fraction and multiply 10 that no. of times.

Comment: @HZXU As you are saying there at most 2 digit after decimal point. So you can check X.YZ whether z is 0 or non zero. if z is 0 multiply by 10 else multiply by 100.

Answer (score 1):

How about taking the float and multiply by 1000 and convert the result to an integer?

Comment: this isn't an answer.. it should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `NSDecimalNumber` and `NSDecimal`.

Answer (score 0):

Float never represents a number with accuracy. The best way is to create a string from "double" number and then do the string manipulation to get the digits after decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
float value = 12.345f;
float integral;
float divisor = 1000.0f;
float fractional = modff(value, &integral);  // breaks a float into fractional and integral parts

int xyz = (int)fmodf(fractional*divisor, divisor);  // modulo (cannot just use %)

NSLog(@"XYZ: %d", xyz); // logs "XYZ: 345"
```

By changing the value of `divisor` you can get the precision you want, e.g. only XY (100.0f) or X (10.0f).

The solution is not the most performant, but useful. I think it could be optimized using bitwise operations.

**Notes on using "f":**

- [What is the significance of 0.0f when initializing (in C)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391818/f-after-number-float-in-objective-c-c?lq=1)
- [“f” after number/float in Objective-C/C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199338/what-is-the-significance-of-0-0f-when-initializing-in-c?lq=1)